# May be an IE z-index bug?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, javascript

Below is my code.

when open the page in ie browser, then select the text in div, the text will be showed by some shadow quad blank . If you delete a line 
  z-index:0, 
in css class test1, the ie will perform correctly.

In my project , the z-index must be set greater than zero, so I couldn't delete the line.

I found a solution is to set bg_img.filter = "" when pannel.z-index greater than 0, then ie will also working good. But unfortunately, the bg_img.filter.alpha must be set, too.

So how could I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script language="javascript" src="scripts/im_test.js"></script>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .test1 {
        position:absolute;
        background:#ffffff;
        left:20px;
        top:20px;
        border:1px solid;
        width:198px;
        height:500px;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color="#999999", Direction=135, Strength=5);
        z-index:0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>

    function init ()
    {
      var pannel = document.createElement ('div');
      var bg_img = document.createElement ('div');
      var head = document.createElement ('div');

      pannel.setAttribute('class', 'test1');
      pannel.setAttribute('className', 'test1');

      bg_img.style.cssText = "position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;"
      + "width:198px;"
      + "height:500px;"
      + "filter:alpha(opacity=100);";

      head.style.cssText = "position:absolute;"
      + "left:0px;"
      + "top:0px;"
      + "width:180px;"
      + "height:20px;";

      document.body.appendChild (pannel);
      pannel.appendChild(bg_img);
      pannel.appendChild(head);

      head.innerHTML = "<div>yusutechasdf</div><div>innerhtml</div>"
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has problems with `z-index: 0;` try setting it to one and adjust other z-indexes accordingly.